# Entity Framework Association Error One to Many

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Can anyone tell my why I am getting this error? I have tried adding constraints but it causing tons of other errors and I cant figure it out. It all looks ok to me :\

This is the error i get

```
Error   1   Error 3003: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 265:Given the cardinality of Association End Member Contact, it should be mapped to key columns of the table tbl_Contact_Relationship. Either fix the mapping or change the multiplicity of this end.
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you're thinking "1 to Many" but in reality it's "0 or 1 to Many".

You can either modify this in the .edmx diagram designer or if you setup the foreign key in your database correctly (make sure you save the table after you exit the dialog window) and 'Update Model from Database' you'll get the mapping corrected automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, have no idea how. Removed the tbl_Contact_Relationship and added it back in and it is working now.